# Akmod Building Nvidia Modules on Every Boot (Fedora)

Tags: fedora, boot, nvidia, kernel-modules

recently my system was suffering from really long boot times so I decided to investigate. `systemd-analyze blame` gives the following output:

```
3min 41.630s akmods.service
3min 39.318s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      9.652s sys-module-fuse.device
      9.597s dev-disk-by\x2dpartuuid-39cbbb9b\x2d02.device
      9.597s sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:17.0-ata1-host0-target0:0:0-0:0:0:0-block-sda-sda>
      9.597s dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:17.0\x2data\x2d1.0\x2dpart2.device
      9.597s dev-disk-by\x2did-wwn\x2d0x5002538f92318a0b\x2dpart2.device
      9.597s dev-sda2.device
      9.597s dev-disk-by\x2did-ata\x2dSamsung_SSD_870_QVO_1TB_S5RRNF1T308525B\x2dpart2.device
      9.597s dev-disk-by\x2ddiskseq-1\x2dpart2.device
      9.596s dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:17.0\x2data\x2d1\x2dpart2.device
      9.596s dev-disk-by\x2duuid-B038A9D338A998BC.device
```

I know akmods is supposed to build modules after an update but it is doing this at every boot, as confirmed by the contents of `/var/log/akmods/akmods.log`:

```
2024/03/24 06:13:06 akmods: Checking kmods exist for 6.7.9-200.fc39.x86_64
2024/03/24 06:13:06 akmods: Building and installing nvidia-kmod
2024/03/24 06:13:06 akmods: Building RPM using the command '/usr/sbin/akmodsbuild --kernels 6.7.9-200.fc39.x86_64 /usr/src/akmods/nvidia-kmod.latest'
2024/03/24 06:16:46 akmods: Installing newly built rpms
2024/03/24 06:16:46 akmods: DNF detected
2024/03/24 06:16:48 akmods: Successful.
2024/03/24 06:25:29 akmods: Checking kmods exist for 6.7.9-200.fc39.x86_64
2024/03/24 06:25:29 akmods: Building and installing nvidia-kmod
2024/03/24 06:25:29 akmods: Building RPM using the command '/usr/sbin/akmodsbuild --kernels 6.7.9-200.fc39.x86_64 /usr/src/akmods/nvidia-kmod.latest'
2024/03/24 06:27:47 akmods: Checking kmods exist for 6.7.9-200.fc39.x86_64
2024/03/24 06:27:47 akmods: Building and installing nvidia-kmod
2024/03/24 06:27:48 akmods: Building RPM using the command '/usr/sbin/akmodsbuild --kernels 6.7.9-200.fc39.x86_64 /usr/src/akmods/nvidia-kmod.latest'
2024/03/24 06:31:25 akmods: Installing newly built rpms
2024/03/24 06:31:25 akmods: DNF detected
2024/03/24 06:31:27 akmods: Successful.
2024/03/24 06:32:31 akmods: Checking kmods exist for 6.7.9-200.fc39.x86_64
2024/03/24 06:32:32 akmods: Building and installing nvidia-kmod
2024/03/24 06:32:32 akmods: Building RPM using the command '/usr/sbin/akmodsbuild --kernels 6.7.9-200.fc39.x86_64 /usr/src/akmods/nvidia-kmod.latest'
2024/03/24 06:36:10 akmods: Installing newly built rpms
2024/03/24 06:36:10 akmods: DNF detected
2024/03/24 06:36:12 akmods: Successful.
```

Is this behavior normal or not, and in both cases how do I fix my boot times?